# Cannot see codelens button "add debug configuration" in template.yaml using aws toolkit for VS code when creating Lambda function

Tags: visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, aws-toolkit

Title says it all.

Codelens appears to be turned on in Preferences.

What else should I look at?

Comment: Try disabling any other extensions you have installed one at a time and then restarting vscode. This happens to me all the time. Anything that adds options in your files will eventually conflict with each other.

Comment: did u fix this?

Comment: In VSCode under settings enable --> Enable SAM hints in source file

Answer (score -1):

I had to install the YAML extension ([YAML Language Support by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml)) to get this to work.